# How would I generate query param key and value and append it to my URL completely dynamically?

Tags: php, debugging

anyone know a good way to dynamically append key value query params at the end of a url that would be generated from an incoming link?

for example: when navigating to `mylocalhost.com/id123?firstParam=test1&secondParam=test2` - this should generate `google.com/id123?firstParam=test1&secondParam=test2`.

I then need to plug this into my anchor tag but that's the easy part.

I read about `http_build_query();` but not sure how to use it in my case since I'm dealing with a string and not an array.

I've looked online but can't seem to find something related to this.  I've also tried a lot of ways to rectify this and make it work but I've ran out of options.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$queryString = "google.com/id123?";

$newUrl = "";

for($i = 0; $i < strlen($queryString); $i++) {
   $newUrl = $queryString . "want=this" . "&" . "tobe=dynamicallyGenerated";
}
```

Comment: `parse_url` and `parse_str` exist, to help take an URL apart into its components, and to parse a query string into an array.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments I think you want to use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, so you get your path as well.

```
<?php
$newURL = 'https://google.com'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
?>
```

Comment: like for example, you give me a url `google.com/id123?test=testing&testTwo=testingTwo`
that google url needs to be generated when I navigate to `mylocalhost.com/id123?test=testing&testTwo=testingTwo`.  The`test=testing&testTwo=testingTwo` part should be dynamic in other words, the user manually writes that.

Comment: This will then allow me to take this URL and plug it into my anchor tag

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230523/discussion-between-someone-and-stackslave).

Comment: `$newURL = 'https://google.com'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` is your solution. Sorry about all my previous typos.